# Output text from NSTask to NSTextField OS X - XCode Objective -C

Tags: macos, text, nstextfield, nstask, output

I was wondering how I would output text from NSTask and send it to a NSTextField on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

I googled NSTask and got [this](http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=nstask)...

but here is the code to do what you want.

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/ls"];

NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-l", @"-a", @"-t", nil];
[task setArguments: arguments];

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

NSString *string;
string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data
                           encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 [myTextField setStringValue: string];
```